# Drupal taxonomy views override path for specific content

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I am beginning to be a little desperate here. I have following structure (Drupal 7):

- I use taxonomy menu to build menu links,
- The taxonomy_term default (page) view is used to override drupal's taxonomy/term/% path

In addition to it I use menu_block module (but I doubt that this is important). What I am trying to achieve:

- I need to build node browser by category (taxonomy term) but it has exceptions - for example taxonomy term with id 850 (taxonomy/term/850) must have different content structure than other therms. Is it possible to override default views display with these exceptions? I tryied to create another display with this path but the result was "not found". I also thought on using blocks not page displays, yet this solutions does not seem to be the Drupal way to me.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem while trying to have different display/structure for publications in contrast to normal articles.

What I did, created a separate view for that specific taxonomy such as *taxonomy/term/850*, and in the path in view I entered '*taxonomy/term/850*' (in this case)

This caused it override *taxonomy/term/%*

and displayed it differently according to my need.